# Find interval for undefined linear equations

Tags: python

I'd like to compute with Python multiple systems of linear equations made up by 3 variables and 2 binding equations each. Knowing that such a system has not single solution, I need to find a range from 0 to 1 (they're probability measures indeed) in which this unknowns may lie. Is there a function in python code that can do so?
Many thanks

Comment: Is this in python?

Comment: yes, I am sorry

Comment: No, it's not in Python.  There are many similarities, but this is not legal Python code.  Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).